# In MySQL Database I want IF else condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a table named `XYZ` with a field called  `Unit_Value` which is of type `DECIMAL(3,2)`, here is some sample data:

```
Unit_Value
--------- 
1.00
1.25
1.75
1.25
0.50
```

My requirement is if `unit_value >= 0` then is should display as 1 if `unit_value <= 1` then display `unit_value`.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT unit_value,
       IF(ROUND(unit_value) = 0, 1, unitvalue) 
  FROM xyz u 
 WHERE unit_value IS NOT NULL;
```

However I don't get the desired result.

Comment: The issue in the last `unitvalue` in the `IF(ROUND(unit_value) = 0, 1, unitvalue)` it has to be `unit_value`. You have missed  "_" in the field name.

Comment: Do you mean `>= 1` not `<= 1`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT unit_value,
       CASE WHEN unit_value >=0 THEN 1 ELSE unit_value END
  FROM xyz u 
 WHERE unit_value IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: It's showing all columns as 1. the column is DECIMAL(3,2) so please let me know

Comment: unit_value >= 0 ,unit_value <= 1 conditions are correct?Clarify you conditions.

Comment: Currently your each values satisfies both conditions!

Comment: Yes but my value are 0.25 , 0.75,1.50 i tried using if condition like below select unitvalue,if(unitvalue<=0,1,unitvalue) from   USER u where unitvalue is not null; bit it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the last `unitvalue` in the`IF(ROUND(unit_value) = 0, 1, unitvalue)` it has to be `unit_value`. You have missed "_" in the field name.

Also for your conditions `(unit_value >= 0 then is should display as 1 if unit_value <= 1)` 
I think it should use [CEILING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling) instead of `ROUND`:

```
SELECT unit_value,
       IF(CEILING(unit_value) = 1, 1, unit_value) 
  FROM xyz u 
 WHERE unit_value IS NOT NULL;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e565d/4)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine, but if it's null value then i.e remove the where condition then how can we control the null values.